# PHP/MySQL Check If Value Exists, If So-Do Not Insert It

Tags: php, mysql

I asked that before, but couldn't figure it out.

I have this form:

```
<?php
if ( isset ($_REQUEST['fname']{0}, $_REQUEST['lname']{0}, $_REQUEST['mail']{0}, $_REQUEST['url']{0}) ){
   $query = "INSERT INTO table1 (url, fname, lname, mail) VALUES ('".$_REQUEST[url]."', '".$_REQUEST[fname]."', '".$_REQUEST[lname]."', '".$_REQUEST[mail]."')"; 
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die ("Query Failed: " . mysql_error());
}
else{
   echo "One Of The Values Not Entered Correctly. Please Press Back In Your Browser And Enter The Missing Values.";
}
?>
```

And I would like to know if it is possible for it to check if a url exists in the system before entering it again.

Comment: Yes, with SQL query. Do you happen to know how to run a query?

Comment: I do indeed: $query = "QUERY";
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die ("Query Failed: " . mysql_error()); The question is: how do i check if it exists?

Comment: @WideBlade What do you want to happen if it does exist?

Comment: It's not a knowledge but rather a copy/paste, but anyway. Well, run a SELECT query and see if it will return anything.

Comment: Col. Shrapnel-you are the kind of people that make people to not want to get into this world. What is wrong with copying somebody Else's code, understanding what it does, and using it for your own purposes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out MySQL [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), which you can use if you set the URL as unique in your database.

Also, you should make sure to sanitize your inputs before inserting them: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 2):

Replace does exactly what you need.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the url column in db is PRIMARY or UNIQUE.

```
ALTER TABLE  `table1` ADD PRIMARY KEY(`url`);
```

#### Before you can use this insert function, you must add mysql_connect(), mysql_select_db()

```
function insert($post = array(), $tb, $announce=true, $ignore="",$updateonduplicate=false){

        foreach($post as $k => $v){
            $fields[$k] = $v;
            $values[] = mysql_real_escape_string($v);
        }

        $query = "INSERT {$ignore} INTO `{$tb}` (`".implode("`,`",array_keys($fields))."`)"." VALUES ('".implode("','",$values)."')";

        if($updateonduplicate !== false){

        $query .= " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ";
        $countfields = 0;
         foreach($fields as $field => $value){

            $query .= " `".$field."`='".$value."'";

            $countfields++;
            if(count($fields) !== $countfields)
            $query .= ",";
         }
        }


//mysql_connect(), mysql_select_db()
// assuming db is connected, database selected
            $result = mysql_query($query)

        if($announce !== true)
        return;


        if(!$result){       
            $announce = "Query Failed: " . mysql_error();

        }else{
            $announce = "insert_success";

        }

        if($updateonduplicate === true && $result === 0 && mysql_affected_rows() >=1){
            $announce = "update_success";
        }   

        return $announce;
    }

$post = array();
$post['url'] = $_REQUEST[url];
$post['fname'] = $_REQUEST[fname];
$post['lname'] = $_REQUEST[lname];
$post['mail'] = $_REQUEST[mail];

insert($post,"table1",true,"",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do have a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` index on the url column, `INSERT IGNORE` will do what you want.  New rows will go in and duplicates will be ignored.  `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will allow you to update if there's a duplicate, if that's what you want to do.  Also, pay good attention to the SQL injection comments from the others here.

Answer (score 0):

Given the description in the OP and subsequent comments (try insert, throw error if exists), I'd simply make sure the required "unique" columns had unique constraints or were part of the primary key.

Then, simply attempt the insert and catch / handle any unique constraint violation errors. This is quicker than checking for existing records.

Using PDO with the error mode set to throw exceptions means you can wrap this code nicely in a try catch block. From memory, unique constraint violations set the exception code to something you can test against.